# jQuery .data context issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm running into a weird issue with trying to attach and retrieve data using $.data. I'm thinking it might be a context issue, but have no idea how to fix this and not sure what exactly is going on?

I have a set of thumbs, each should have it's own data associated with it. When the script is called, this fires which pulls all of the plugin's default settings, does it's normal thing, then pulls all of the data-Plugin settings from each thumbnail's parent ('a') tag and merges that. Lastly, I'm assigning that full set of merged Plugin settings to the thumbnail's $.data and finally assigning a click event to it.

```
return this.each(function(index){ 
   var $this=$(this), 
       objSRC=$this.parents('a:first'),
       dataSettings=(!objSRC.data("plugin"))?{}:JSON.parse(objSRC.attr('data-plugin')),
       mergedData=$.extend({}, Plugin.settings,dataSettings||{});

    $.data($this, mergedData); 

    // SETUP THUMBNAIL CLICK EVENT  
    $this.on('click',function(e){ 
       Plugin.thumbClick($this); 
       e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

.... then in the actual thumbnail click event method is where I'm running into an issue:

```
thumbClick:function(obj){
   var objData=$.data(obj), 
       objParent=obj.parents('a:first'),
       GalAttr=obj[0].getAttribute('rel'), 
       imageATTR=this.alt;

   // SETUP GALLERIES IN ARRAY INSIDE DATA - ONCE
   if((typeof(GalAttr)!='undefined' && GalAttr) && !obj[0]['Galleries']){
      var GallerySet=$("[rel='"+GalAttr+"']");
      for(var i=0,l=GallerySet.length; i<l; ++i){ 
          GallerySet[i]['Galleries']=GallerySet; 
      };
   };   
},
```

Inside the method I've setup some basic variables, then I'm working with the thumbnail's rel attribute. The rel attribute is being used to group thumbnails into galleries. So, upon clicking the thumbnail I'm trying to

1) Pull the REL attribute from the thumbnail (obj)

2) Find all similar thumbnails on the page with the same rel attribute (once)

3) Save that returned collection as an array to the thumbnail's data

This way, I'll only need to search the DOM based on 'rel' once per gallery. After that everything will be stored inside a 'Galleries' array in the thumbnail's $.data. Everything looks correct and is working, but I'm running into 1 issue - the $.data isn't aligning properly between the thumbnail (obj) that's passed in to the function and the ones I've search for and added to the Galleries array.

Basically if I 
console.log(obj) and 
console.log($(GallerySet[0]))

when clicking on the first image in a Gallery I get the exact same element. (both are objects) But, when I try to pull the data from each:

console.log($.data(obj) and
console.log($.data($(GallerySet[0]))

they're completely different. $.data(obj) (which is the thumbnail that was clicked and passed in to the thumbClick method) is returning the data object correctly, but the other is returning an empty object.

Does anyone have ideas or insight into this issue? Thanks!